# Multiple websites within IIS running with different time zone settings

Tags: iis, timezone, locale

Is there a way to have multiple websites running within IIS that have different time zone information?

For example: The local Windows Server is running in CST.
I would like one website that runs in CST and a second website that runs in EST.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. This article should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832986/how-to-work-with-timezone-in-asp-net

Comment: Just a clarification: I am not asking about UTC or handling time zones inside of code. I would like the process that's running the server to be different. Example: Windows says it's 5PM but but the server process says it's 4PM. Without any code that I write having to do any time conversions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a configuration that you would control within IIS, rather, you would make sure that each website is written to be able input and output from/to multiple time zones. The link provided by GrimFandango gives a good overview of how to do that.