# How can you set time zone setting per user?

Tags: windows, user-profile, timezone

Is there a way to set the time zone information to be unique for each Windows user? Like, a registry setting specific to that user.

For example, I want John to be CST and Mary to be PST. If John opens a program it says 5pm. If Mary opens a program it says 6pm.

Additional information: These users don't need to actually log in. I want to create two users, one for CST and one for PST, and use their credentials to run a program. The program will inherit their time zone settings and display the correct time.

More info: I plan on using these users in IIS for app pools so that different applications in the website can be run in different time zones and locales.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple websites within IIS running with different time zone settings](http://serverfault.com/questions/211475/multiple-websites-within-iis-running-with-different-time-zone-settings)

Comment: You've also asked this once here already, and on StackOverflow as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413987/multiple-websites-within-iis-running-with-different-time-zone-settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way Windows supports this is through Terminal Services, which won't help you. The time-zone settings are kept in the HKLM hive, and Terminal Services has a special setting that allows the Terminal Server to take a time-zone supplied by the incoming client-session and display that instead.

A better plan would be to use the timezone offsets in your code. StackOverflow is a better place to ask about that.

Comment: @James Carnley: You can set the timezone via command line (in a batch file for instance) but as sysadmin1138 says, it's a per machine setting, not a per user setting.

Answer (score -3):

I haven't tried, but perhaps via cygwin you can use the TZ Environmental variable like under Unix/Linux.  Env variables can be set on the command line by placing them before the command called - eg `TZ=UTC xxxx`.