# how can i change the timezone in asp

Tags: asp.net, time

I'm looking for a way to change the time zone in asp, as I was searching, I figured the we can do it through web.config file, but didn't know how to set it to be sync with Jordan time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832986/how-to-work-with-timezone-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "change the timezone"? The current timezone setting is a property of the Windows profile and so belongs to the user identity that your w3wp.exe process runs under. There is no per-thread setting like there is for CultureInfo.

In my applications when I need custom timezone support I store a TimeZoneInfo object as part of an application's user's settings (and stored in Session state). Internally all dates and times are UTC and I just convert these UTC values to local using the user's TimeZoneInfo instance during render-time. I suggest you do something similar:

```
// At user login or session start
Session["TimeZone"] = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Jordan Standard Time");

// Static helper extension method to make local
public static DateTime ToLocal(this DateTime utcDateTime) {
    TimeZoneInfo tz = Session["TimeZone"];
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc( utcDateTime, tz );
}

// Use in ASP.NET page
<%= myDateTimeValue.ToLocal() %>
```