# getting datetime for users with respect to their location

Tags: c#, sql-server

My application is using sql server a database. I am looking for way if user login from US, then the US time will appear on the website. And if user is from UK then UK standard time should appear,

My question is: is there a way I can get date and time with respect to user's location. I am tracking users' ip address and so I know where the user's location.

Is there any solution I can do this in sql server and C#

Comment: can you use html/javascript?

Comment: Sorry, but why you need this? I think it's client side problem.

Comment: Isn't there any sql server feature that I can use to retrieve respected date and time? I have the location I just want to feed this to sql server and can't I get what I\ wanted

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't depend on the server and IP Adresses to do this. Your user could use a proxy in Japan, while sitting in South Africa.

To get a clients time I'd simply use javascript:

```
var dateTimeNow = new Date();
```

Of course, if you are using a desktop client with Winforms or WPF then it is simply `DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()`.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is, store the transaction related `DateTime` in UTC format in your DB, and display the `DateTime` based on the TimeZone in UI. If you want just display the DateTime in UI, use client side script for getting local `DateTime`.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/832999/311255) has more details about storing/retrieving `DateTime`.