# Setting different time zone in IIS or web.config

Tags: c#, iis, timezone

I am logging time in many places

```
If Request.DynamicSettings.AirlineSettings.AirlineGeneralSettings.TimeLogEnabled Then
                        StartTime = DateTime.Now
                        LogTime(Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.DeclaringType.FullName, Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name, StartTime, DateTime.Now, "AB-SCR(I)", 0,)
    End If
```

all places i have used

> DateTime.Now

I am facing an issue now, 
I am currently hosting this in a gulf server, GMT +4:00
I need to host this same project for another country at Gmt +3Gmt
for this hosting i need time to be logged using that country's local time.

Is there any way to do this, without having to modify each and every line of my code.

i have seen this article [timzone with asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832986/how-to-work-with-time-zones-in-asp-net) but as my service is already up i have a lot of codes to change, i am looking for a simpler solution.

thanks.

Comment: What happens inside `LogTime`? Are you logging the actual time of day? Or are you subtracting the two `DateTime` values to measure how long the action took?

Comment: i just put a part of the code, this is for calculating time diffrence, what i really mean is about the datetime.now() function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A few things:

1. You cannot change the time zone in the IIS configuration or web.config.  This is not an IIS problem, but rather a problem in your application code.
2. `DateTime.Now` should never be used in a server side application, such as an ASP.Net web application.  Read [The case against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).
3. If you are just timing how long something takes to run, don't use `DateTime` at all.  Instead, use [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch).

   ```
   Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
   // ...do some work ...
   sw.Stop();
   TimeSpan elapsed = sw.Elapsed;  // how long it took will be in the Elapsed property
   ```
4. If you actually want the current time in a specific time zone, then you need to know the time zone identifier.  (GMT+4 and GMT+3 are not time zones, but rather *time zone offsets*  see "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).)  You can see a list of Windows time zones by using `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()`, or by calling `tzutil /l` on the command line.

   Then in your application:

   ```
   string tz = "Arabian Standard Time";
   DateTime now = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, tz);
   ```

   You should probably refactor your code such that this is done inside your `LogTime` method.  Then you will have only one place to set the time zone for your application.