# My Asp.net Application is using servertime Zone which is 12 and half hour behind Indian time .How to resolve

Tags: c#, asp.net

My Asp.net Application is using servertime Zone which is 12 and half hour behind Indian time .Already tried below things
GetDate function
DateTime.Now

Comment: Please check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832986/how-to-work-with-time-zones-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the result by add time in universal time zone.

```
static DateTime mydt;DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;DateTime dt2 = dt1.ToUniversalTime();TimeSpan t1 = new TimeSpan(5, 30, 0);//for ISTDateTime dt3 = dt2.Add(t1);mydt = dt3;
```